# jQuery Swap Images In A Sequence

Tags: jquery

I'm a jQuery novice to say the least so please bear with me here.

I need to swap out some images in a timed sequence. I found a tutorial online which kind of does what I need. Here is the code:

```
function swapImagesMaps(){
var $active = $('#maps .active');
var $next = ($('#maps .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#maps .active').next() : $('#maps img:first');
$active.fadeOut(function(){
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
    });
```

}

```
setInterval('swapImagesMaps()', 2000);
```

This is cool, but I have 4 different div containers with images in them, and I want them to fade every 2 seconds.

So div1 will change and then 2 seconds later div2 will change, and so on. Once it loops through all 4 div containers, it will go back to div1 and change that one again and just keep cycling through.

Hopefully this makes sense and I appreciate any help or suggestions!

Comment: You should not pass a string to `setInterval`.

Comment: dont use eval(javascript in strings). `setInterval(swapImagesMaps, 2000);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://www.adventure-service.com/)? I am using [this jQuery Carousel](http://thomlx.free.fr/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm).

Just include that js file and call it like this:

```
        $('#banner_container').carousel({
            autoSlide: true, 
            autoSlideInterval: 4000,
            pagination: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `<div>` elements in an array, then use an incrementing index to determine which element to change.

Comment: SLaks thanks for the suggestion. Any chance you could throw me a quick reference/example to do that? Like I said, I'm a novice at best.